# Numerical solution of $2D$ wave equation using Fourier transform and finite differences

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, wave-equation, finite-differences

This is the $2$-dimensional wave equation

$$ u_{tt} = u_{xx} + u_{yy} $$

with initial condition $u(x,y,0)=f(x,y)$ and $u_{t}(x,y,0) = 0$.

The inverse Fourier transform used is

$$ u(x,y,t) = \iint \hat{u}(\omega_{x}, \omega_{y}, t)e^{(2\pi) \omega_{x}i x} e^{(2\pi) \omega_{y} i y}d\omega_{x} d\omega_{y} $$

this is also the version that is used by Matlab's FFT. Applying this to wave equation we get

$$ \iint \hat{u}_{tt}e^{(2\pi) \omega_{x}i x} e^{(2\pi) \omega_{y}i y}d\omega_{x} d\omega_{y}   = (2 \pi)^{2} (\omega_{x}^{2} + \omega_{y}^{2})  \iint \hat{u} e^{(2\pi) \omega_{x} i x} e^{(2\pi) \omega_{y} i y}d\omega_{x} d\omega_{y}  $$
so the Wave equation in frequency space is:

$$ \hat{u}_{tt} = -(2\pi)^{2} (\omega_{x}^{2} + \omega_{y}^{2})  \hat{u} $$

Although this gives exact solution very easy, I tried to solve it numerically using Matlab.

The numerical method I used is finite difference:

$$ \hat{u}_{tt} \approx \frac{\hat{u}_{t}(t) - \hat{u}_{t}(t-\Delta t)}{ \Delta t} $$
$$ \approx \frac{\hat{u}(t) - 2 \hat{u}(t- \Delta t)  + \hat{u}(t - 2\Delta t)}{ (\Delta t)^{2}}  $$

And for the initial condition: $\hat{u}(\Delta t) = \hat{u}(0)$.

I did it successfully in 1D case, $\hat{u}(\omega,t)_{tt} = (2\pi \omega)^{2}\hat{u}(\omega,t)$, using similar formulation. But I get something wrong in the solution in 2D case, the solution does not blow up but the behavior does not match the exact solution (using Gaussian curve as initial condition, then the wave should split with it's height equals half of the initial height, instead it decays drastically). See animation below:

[image]

---

**Matlab code**

```
clear;
tic;

dx = 0.005; dy = 0.005;
xmax = 1; xmin = -1;
ymax = 1; ymin = -1;
periodx = xmax-xmin; periody = ymax-ymin;
x = [(xmin):dx:(xmax)];
y = [(ymin):dy:(ymax)];
nx = length(x);
ny = length(y);
multiplierx = (1)/periodx;
multipliery = (1)/periody;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

if (mod(nx,2) == 0)
    w_right = [0:1:((nx/2)-1)];
    w_left = [(-nx/2):1:-1];
    w = [w_right, w_left];
    wx = multiplierx*w;
else  
    w_right = [0:1:(((nx-1)/2))];
    w_left = [(-(nx-1)/2):1:-1];
    w = [w_right, w_left];
    wx = multiplierx*w;
end

if (mod(ny,2) == 0)
w_right = [0:1:((ny/2)-1)];
w_left = [(-ny/2):1:-1];
w = [w_right, w_left];
wy = multipliery*w;
else  
w_right = [0:1:(((ny-1)/2))];
w_left = [(-(ny-1)/2):1:-1];
w = [w_right, w_left];
wy = multipliery*w;
end

[Wx, Wy] = meshgrid(wx, wy);

f = @(x,y) 0.5*exp(-(x.^2 + y.^2)/0.1);
Z = f(X,Y);

dt = 0.005;
t = [0:dt:2]; nt = length(t);

u(:,:, 1) = f(X, Y);
u(:,:, 2) = f(X, Y);

uhat(:,:,1) = fft2(u(:,:, 1));
uhat(:,:,2) = fft2(u(:,:, 2));


surfl(u(:,:,1));
zlim([-1,1]);
view([0, 0]);
colormap(winter);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
shading interp;

for i = [3:1:nt]

  uhat(:,:,i) = (uhat(:,:,i-1) + (uhat(:, :, i-1) - uhat(:, :, i-2)))./(1 + (((dt*2*pi)^2)*(Wx.^2 + Wy.^2)));
  u(:,:,i) = real(ifft2(uhat(:,:,i)));
  uhat(:,:,i) = fft2(u(:,:,i));
  disp(i);  
end 

toc;

for i = [1:1:nt]  
  surfl(u(:,:,i));
  zlim([-1,1]);
  view([0, 0]);
  colormap(winter);
  shading interp;
  pause(0.01)
end
```

Comment: Use `\iint` for double integrals and `\Delta` instead of `\triangle`.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com may be a better home for this question.

Comment: Your Fourier transform formulas are wrong consistently, they are is missing the complex unit in the exponent and the resulting sign in the second derivative. The code appears done with the correct formula.

Comment: @LutzLehmann fixed it, but the result should be correct.

Comment: By using the FFT you have applied periodic (or reflecting?) boundary conditions. The domain is rather small, so a "natural" behavior is not to be expected. For that your result does not look wrong.

Comment: @LutzLehmann But it worked in the 1D case, perfectly. I tried for bigger boundary, it still does not look like the exact solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann * I meant I tried the 2D in bigger domain, still not solved.

Comment: Your expectations of 2d solution are incorrect and apply only to 1d solution. In 2d the solution decays as the wave travels away from the origin